# How bad is the word, “bitch”?

Tags: vocabulary, slang

I saw a movie, and a character called her mom "**a raging bitch**" while writing an email.

How bad is the swear word "bitch"? Is it even okay to call your mom "bitch"..?

Comment: "Is it even okay to call your mom "bitch"..?" No.

Comment: If you use the word there are certainly people who will bitch about it.

Comment: -1 For the simple answer, try calling s woman coworker a bitch and see how she reacts. It has always been my view that there is a significant difference between acting "bitchy" and being called a "bitch", between calling oneself "bitch" and calling another with the same epithet. The former can even be a badge of honour depending in context, but there is nowhere "raging bitch" is an OK thing to call someone. Please use a dictionary.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Please don't write answers in comments; they are harmful to our site. Doing
so bypasses our community-moderated quality measures by not permitting
community editing or paired up- and down-voting available on comments, as
well as having [other problems detailed on
meta](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1644/3171). Comments 
are for clarifying and improving the question; please don't use them for
other purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In american English and among certain groups of young people it is possible to call a friend a bitch and get away with it, provided this is done in a "friendly" manner which gives away that the locutor isn't really mad, not really full of hatred, but rather amused, wondering, etc. at the behaviour that is the cause for this pseudo-insult. But that is very exceptional; in particular, if the locutor calls his/her mother a bitch, this "friendly" manner will not at all be interpreted favourably; the respect due to a mother or any other relative  forbids strictly such language in speaking to them, although if speaking to a sister or a cousin it becomes possible (in this "friendly" manner). It is otherwise a very offensive word that will result in much anger.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it is very insulting. Technically - and neutrally - it refers to the female of a species, but to apply it to a human suggests unflatteringly that the woman is merely animal. I have seen it in the context of sexual encounters where the two partners enjoy their mutual reduction to animality, but in most contexts it is insulting and should be used with great care.

Comment: My aunt breeds terriers, and refuses to stop calling the males "dogs", and the females "bitches", even though some over-sensitive souls flinch when she does the latter.

Comment: :) I have clarified my answer accordingly.

Comment: How far is 'very'? That is, What is the degree of upset, tabooness, vulgarity/acceptability? It is one thing to be called to your face a word, another to use it third person. Eg, 'c..t' in almost all contexts awful (maybe worse than 'f..k' or 'n....r') in US English. But 'bitch' is not as bad as that. It's worse than 'stupid'. Where on the continuum needs to be addressed

Comment: Some women call themselves bitches. ("I can be a bitch at times.") And people also refer to inanimate objects as "real bitches." In neither of these contexts is there any insult.

Comment: True, and in both cases there is a pejorative feeling to bitch. The inanimate bitch presents difficulties ("This mower is a bitch to start"). Even when applied to oneself it implies at least that I can be difficult and irritable.